# How to get model of selected menu item

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have paper-menu with some paper-items. How can I get model of selected paper-item in my click paper-item handler? Thank you

```
<paper-menu selected="{{route}}">
              <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ajaxResponse.body.tags]]">
                <paper-item>
                  <a class="page-router" data-route$="[[item.name]]" href="[[_computeHref(item)]]">
                    <iron-icon icon$="[[_computeIconItem(item)]]" class$="[[_computeIconClass(item)]]"></iron-icon>
                    <paper-item-body class="sputnik-menu-item-text">[[item.name]]</paper-item-body>
                  </a>
                </paper-item>
              </template>
            </paper-menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ev.model.item` on event handler